# opening dictionaries in bool data type

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

we could open a dictionary with **:

```
dict = {"v_1":"a","v_2":"b"}
function(**dict) >
function(v_1 = "a",v_2 = "b")
```

So is it possible to open dictionaries to represent bool expressions so:

```
dict = {"v_1":"a","v_2":"b"}
function(???) > 
function(v_1 == "a",v_2 == "b")
```

where i want to use this process:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#inserts-updates-and-deletes
in this code as an example:
`tmt = users.update().where(users.c.name == 'jack').values(name='ed')`
on where function `.where(users.c.name == 'jack').`
I also have a dictionary:
`{"name":"jack"}`
Is there any way I can pass this dictionary to the function as desired?

Comment: `v_1` is a string, not a variable, so you want a dict where value==key ?

Comment: So, if understand correctly, your called function will receive `True,True` when passed {"v_1":"v_1","v_2":"v_2"}. Is that right?

Comment: @BoarGules I wrote where I want to use the operation I want. but I guess there is no way to use this. I will look at the different ways of selecting.

Comment: @azro I wrote where I want to use the operation I want. but I guess there is no way to use this. I will look at the different ways of selecting.

Answer (score 0):

Check **kwargs structure. You can see an example below.

```
def function(*args,**kwargs):
    for i in args:
        print(i)
    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        print('key: ',k,'value: ',v)
 
function(1,2,3,'args' , val = 'kwargs')
```

output

```
#1
#2
#3
#args
#key: val value: kwargs
```

Comment: In the question OP makes it clear he knows what `**kwargs` does and that it isn't what he wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

What I did not understand when asking the question is that the operator `==` is not a bool value! was used as an object constructor. so `v_1 == "a"` was creating an object with v1. I've done this by scrolling through a list for now. Although it's not exactly the answer I wanted, my solution is:

```
dict = {"v_1":"a","v_2":"b"}
list = []
for i in dict:
    list.append(i == dict[i])
function(*l)
```